# Remove a file from Perforce control without deleting from workspace?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to remove files/directories from Perforce's control without deleting the file from the client workspace?

I'm indifferent about what happens to the files/dirs in the repository, I want to ensure that they *ARE NOT* removed from my local workspace.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a little more context on why you need the files removed from Perforce (does that just mean you want them writeable?) and why you need them to stay in your local workspace afterwards?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor, unsure about asker's situation, but I've accidentally added files that are of interest only to me and wanted to remove them.  i.e. IDE config files

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
p4 delete -k <file>
```

It will update the server, but not touch the workspace.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/delete.html

Comment: No deal, from the latest p4 download:

    `>p4 delete -k .settings`
    `Usage: add/edit/delete [-c changelist#] [ -f -n ] [-t type] files...`
    `Invalid option: -k.`

Comment: Support for `delete -k` was added in the 2011.1 server.
(http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r11.1/manuals/cmdref/delete.html)

Comment: Argh, I have no say on the server-side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not connected to a server that supports the -k switch on the delete command, you can create a new workspace that has a different root, delete the files from there, then switch back to your original workspace.  Because the new workspace has a different root, the files in your original workspace won't be touched.

Comment: Won't the files get deleted on the next sync, though? I think you'd need to use flush on the original workspace to make sure it doesn't try to sync the deleted files.

Comment: I ended-up going brute force on this, saving everything away, letting Perforce do it thing, then adding back files I needed. Ugh.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor: Yes, once the files are in version control, that is a problem.  I think the OP wants to unbind the files from version control, not just delete them.  That would require use of the obliterate command.

Comment: And how do you obliterate? In any case it shouldn't remove history. It should still be the case that the file was once there, but the "history" should show it is no longer bound.

(git is better here you just add it to .gitignore).

Answer (score 0):

You can shelve the files and then delete the "shelved files" in perforce, your local files should be intact.